# Как назначить команду в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В `MyClass` есть метод `MyMethod`. Помогите разобраться, как с помощью команд назначить этот метод елементу `Button`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Команда на элемент назначается так

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyMethodCommand}" ...>Execute</Button>
```

Чтобы это назначение работало, надо либо реализовывать ICommand либо использовать объекты RoutedCommand или RoutedUICommand. Например

```
private DelegateCommand myMethodCommand; 
public ICommand MyMethodCommand
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if(myMethod== null) 
            myMethod= new DelegateCommand(new Action(MyMethodExecuted), 
                new Func<bool>(MyMethodCanExecute)); 
        return myMethodCommand; 
    } 
} 
public bool MyMethodCanExecute() 
{ 
    return true; 
} 
public void MyMethodExecuted() 
{ 
    // TODO:
}
```

- [Знакомство с маршрутизированными событиями и командами в WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc785480.aspx)
- [Общие сведения о системе команд](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752308.aspx)